# Cannot figure out gmail pub sub to send JSON notifications

Tags: php, gmail-api

Maybe I'm a little too plebish, but I can not figure out how to send json data to my script when I receive email.

I have topic setup, I have granted permission given to `gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com` and I even added my domain and created subscribtion.

I need help with setting that it would send data to my url http://example.com/pubsub/takejson.php, that files takes incoming json data and stores json decoded data in text file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I'm asking for someone, who worked with gmail push notifications pub sub thingy, to help me out a little bit, setting up, so when I receive email, I would get POST notification to my php script

Comment: You will have better luck if you improve your question  as i mentioned you may want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How to setup gmail push notifications (pubsub thing), so I could receive them in my custom script.

I can't rewrite it more simplier...